# SQL RBS "the URL is invalid" error when trying to upload a file (SP 2010)

Tags: remote-blob-storage, rbs

I'm trying to setup Sharepoint 2010 (SQL Server 2008) to use [SQL RBS](http://sqlrbs.codeplex.com/) for testing purposes. I followed all the steps required and in the process created a local folder C:\RBS_Store which serves as a BLOB store. The code samples (run from cmd) can access C:\RBS_Store and work fine. However, when I try to upload a file to a Sharepoint site from the browser/user interface, I get the following error:

> The URL '*file I'm trying to upload*' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web.

and the file is neither uploaded to be seen in the browser nor it gets stored in the C:\RBS_Store. I have no such problem if I use the default FILESTREAM RBS provider.

OS: Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2 x64

Sharepoint log reveals that before the error is displayed, this is what happens:

> Exception thrown storing stream in new SqlRemoteBlob:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: **The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.ConfigItemList'  threw an exception.**
>   ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I'm guessing this has something to do with permissions, but am not exactly sure what/where to look for. Any ideas or help would be apperciated.